# How to load data through argument parser in python?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, computer-vision, arguments, ocr

**I'm unable to load data into the code and parse it. I'm attaching the below code**

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-a", "--az", required=True,
    help="path to A-Z dataset")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", type=str, required=True,
    help="path to output trained handwriting recognition model")
ap.add_argument("-p", "--plot", type=str, default="plot.png",
    help="path to output training history file")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

The above followed by below code

```
# load the A-Z and MNIST datasets, respectively
print("[INFO] loading datasets...")
(azData, azLabels) = load_az_dataset(args["az"])
(digitsData, digitsLabels) = load_mnist_dataset()
```

I have the data, image and model saved

My data structure looks like this

```
.
├── a_z_handwritten_data.csv
├── handwriting.model
├── plot.png
├── train_ocr_model.ipynb
└── train_ocr_model.py
```

The error is given below:

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-a", "--az", required=True,
    help="path to A-Z dataset")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", type=str, required=True,
    help="path to output trained handwriting recognition model")
ap.add_argument("-p", "--plot", type=str, default="plot.png",
    help="path to output training history file")
    args = vars(ap.parse_args())

usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] -a AZ -m MODEL [-p PLOT]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: the following arguments are required: -a/--az, -m/--model
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2
```

Another error is:

```
print("[INFO] loading datasets...")
(azData, azLabels) = load_az_dataset(r'a_z_handwritten_data.csv')
(digitsData, digitsLabels) = load_mnist_dataset()
[INFO] loading datasets...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-1e649190daf8> in <module>
      4 
      5 print("[INFO] loading datasets...")
----> 6 (azData, azLabels) = pd.read_csv(r'a_z_handwritten_data.csv')
      7 (digitsData, digitsLabels) = load_mnist_dataset()

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: Your approach seems to be in order, so what is the real problem? Is there an error while running the code? (if yes please provide the error), is the file empty? (if yes, check if you can replace the `args["az"]` with your direct path and see if that works. So make small steps, first verify that `load_az_dataset` works with the path. Then set a default argument to that path and finally remove the default argument and test your terminal input of the path. Lastly, if you are running the programming from a different folder, make sure the path is relative from where you run your script.

Comment: Can you please write that code? That would be really helpful. It's really difficult to understand.

Comment: I've mentioned the errors also. Please check and help me with this.

Comment: I was giving options, but from the error it seems that your function `load_az_dataset` is not returning a tuple of the two values `(azData, azLabels)`, but only a single value. Print the output of the function (`print(load_az_dataset(args['az']))`) and verify your output is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your following code

```
(azData, azLabels) = load_az_dataset(r'a_z_handwritten_data.csv')
```

Replace the above code segment with the following code.

```
hand_written_data = load_az_dataset(r'a_z_handwritten_data.csv')
```

Then this issue will be fixed. Visit the following link for more details about the error. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html